# wxPython grid formatting

Tags: python, grid, wxpython

I have a wxPython GUI with a grid in it.  I can't predict the exact size of the grid before it is created.  My problem is the way the grid scrollbars display when the user clicks on a cell to edit.  This is particularly apparent the grid has only one row, which can happen occasionally; if you select a cell to edit, the scrollbars pop up in such a way that you can't see the row at all.  I don't want the user to have to scroll within the grid at all (in my GUI, the grid is in a wx.ScrolledWindow).

I need to have some buttons and directions outside of the grid, so having the grid object 'stand alone' is not a good option for me.

Here is the code:

```
class Spacing(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Fix spacing")                                                                                            
        self.panel = wx.ScrolledWindow(self)
        self.InitUI()


    def InitUI(self):
        label = wx.StaticText(self.panel,label="hello")#, size=(500, 50))                                                         
        grid = self.make_table(1, 5)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(label, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        vbox.Add(grid, flag=wx.BOTTOM|wx.EXPAND, border=20)

        hbox_all= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox_all.AddSpacer(20)
        hbox_all.AddSpacer(vbox)
        hbox_all.AddSpacer(20)

        self.panel.SetSizer(hbox_all)
        self.panel.SetScrollbars(20, 20, 50, 50)
        hbox_all.Fit(self)
        self.Show()


    def make_table(self, n_cols, n_rows):
        grid = wx.grid.Grid(self.panel, -1)
        grid.ClearGrid()
        grid.CreateGrid(n_cols, n_rows)
        for n in range(n_cols):
            for num in range(n_rows):
                grid.SetCellValue(n, num, (str(num) + str(n)))
        return grid

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    app.frame = Spacing()
    app.frame.Show()
    app.frame.Center()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I can imagine a few options.  One, if I could add some "padding" to the grid window, the user would still be able to see what they were editing no matter what.  Two, if I could override the scrolled window nature of the grid, that would work also.  I haven't figured
 out how to do either of these, and I'm open to other suggestions.  I've tried messing with disabling grid.SetAutoLayout and manually sizing the grid, but neither of these has proven effective.  I would really appreciate any suggestions!

The (very) hack-y solution I've devised is to make sure to have another widget in the container window that is wider than the grid and also set the grid to wx.EXPAND, which prevents the horizontal scrollbars from ever popping up.

That is, I replace this line of code:

```
    label = wx.StaticText(self.panel,label="hello")
```

with this:

```
    label = wx.StaticText(self.panel,label="hello", size=(500, 50))
```

and this line:

```
    vbox.Add(grid, flag=wx.BOTTOM, border=20)
```

with this:

```
    vbox.Add(grid, flag=wx.BOTTOM|wx.EXPAND, border=20)
```

This option looks a little weird too, but it doesn't obscure what the user is typing.  Obviously this is not a good solution, but I haven't been able to figure out how to actually fix the problem.

Update:

If I create the grid with a set spacing it doesn't re-size:

```
    grid = wx.grid.Grid(self.panel, -1, size = (500, 300))
```

But if I create the grid and then try to re-size it, it doesn't "stick" and I have the same objectionable behavior as before.  In fact, grid.SetSize doesn't seem to work at all visually, even though when I call grid.GetSize() it reports being the size I have assigned.

```
    grid.SetSize(wx.Size(500, 300))
```

Comment: What platform and what versions are you using?  I can't see grid scrollbars in your sample, only scrollsbars of the ScrolledWindow show when I resize, this even after removing the StaticText and reducing Border to 5.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.6 --  64-bit and wxPython 2.9.2.4-1 on a Mac 10.9.5.  For me, the grid scrollbars don't show up until I double click on a cell for editing.  This doesn't show up for you?

Comment: I am on Windows and wxPython 3.0.1.1 and I don't get scrollbars.

Comment: 2.9.2 is pretty old, can you upgrade to 3.0.1.1 and try with that?

Comment: @Werner Unfortunately I can't -- I am using the Enthought Python distribution and that only has up through 2.9.2.  I need to use the Enthought distribution for other specialized packages like Basemap.  I haven't gotten a response from them as to when/if they will be providing a more up recent version of wxPython.  For now, I guess my hack-y solution will have to do.  Thanks for your input...